# Шифр с перестановкой букв на Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, шифрование

*Здравствуйте*. Мне необходимо написать шифровщик на Python, который будет попарно менять буквы местами друг с другом.

Например: *холод* = *ох ол д - охолд*

Но как это реализовать, я не понимаю.

В мой голове была идея, что когда человек вводит текст, текст сначала сравнивается с элементами массива (алфавит русского языка), потом каждая буква с четным индексом менялась местами с буквой с нечетным индексом. Так бы получился шифр. Но к примеру `"а" = [0]` и как мне делить на `2` число `0`?

Не вариант.

И тем более мне нужно, чтобы к каждой букве написанного текста была присвоена цифра, которую я уже и буду делить.

Помогите идеей или функцией.
Пожалуйста.
Мне шифр нужен до завтра.

Comment: парсишь строку, берешь i ый и i + 1 ый, и записываешь в строку i + 1, i ый

Comment: Какова цель сравнивания с алфавитом? Делить ничего не надо, как и присваивать цифры буквам. Нужно же просто поменять две рядом стоящие буквы - 1-ю со 2-й, 3-ю с 4-й итд.

Comment: `''.join(s[i+1:i+2]+s[i] for i in range(0,len(s),2))`

Comment: Спасибо всем вам за помощь!^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью срезов: "отрезаем" от строки первые 2 символа, печатаем их перевернутыми, повторяем пока строка не кончится

```
x = 'перераспределение'

while x:
    x1 = x[:2]
    print(x1[::-1], end='')
    x = x[2:]
```

вывод:
`еперарпсеределине`

Comment: Ты мне очень сильно помог, я счастлив. Спасибо